# Error Box div is coming and going off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When i run register.html, and click on register button without selecting anything in clist it should show the errorbox div and remain on the page until i dont click register button again. but what is happening that the errorbox div is shown for a second and then vanishes away. Can anybody pls tel me wht is this happening.

register.js

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#reg").click(function(){

if($('#clist option:selected').text()=='Select...')
{
    $("#errorBox").html("Please fill in all the fields. All the * marked fields are123 important");

}
//$('#ddlList option:selected').text()
     });
});
```

registration.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>JobSeeker Registration Page </title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ex.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="errorBox"></div>
<form  class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="#">

<div class="page-header paddi">
<h4>
Create Login Details
</h4>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">

<label class="control-label col-md-3 text-right" for="email"> Enter your Email id<sup>*</sup>:
</label>

<div class="col-md-7">
<input type="text" name="eml" id="eml" />
</div>
</div>

<div  class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-md-3 text-right" for="clist">
Where are you currently located<sup>*</sup>: 
</label>
<div class="col-md-7">
<select id="clist">
<option value="">Select...</option>
<option value="Sweden"> India </option>
<option value="Denmark"> USA </option>
<option value="Norway"> Norway </option>
<option value="Finland"> Finland </option>
<option value="Iceland"> Iceland </option>
</select>

</div>

</div>
<div class="control-group">
                                <!-- Button -->
                                <div class="controls col-md-offset-3 col-md-2">
                                    <button class="btn btn-success" id="reg">Register</button>
                                </div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: seems to me your `form` gets submitted anyway. put an `e.preventDefault` inside the `click` function with `e` taken as parameter to this callback.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is being submitted

Add `event.preventDefault()` to your click handler to make it work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#reg").click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        if ($('#clist option:selected').text() == 'Select...') {
            $("#errorBox").html("Please fill in all the fields. All the * marked fields are123 important");

        }
        //$('#ddlList option:selected').text()
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

seems to me your `form` gets submitted anyway. put an `e.preventDefault` inside the `click` function with `e` taken as parameter to this callback.

```
$('#reg').click(function (e) {
    if ($('#clist option:selected').text() == 'Select...') {
        $('#errorBox').html('Please fill in all the fields. All the * marked fields are123 important');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```